# awk getline from a Pipe '"cmd" | getline var' caches its value

Tags: awk

As part of a larger `awk` script I needed to convert an arbitrary date string into seconds since the Epoch. This isn't available as an `awk` function so I thought I could resort to calling `date` on each line of input. (In hindsight I could have used `perl`, but let's park that thought.)

After seeing some unexpected results I reduced the problem to this (`bash` and GNU `awk`)

```
for f in {1..5}; do echo $f; sleep 2; done | awk '{ "date" | getline x; printf ">>%s<<\n", x }'
```

All the same result, even though I confirmed that the `awk` loop really is running only once every two seconds

```
>>29 Jun 2020 10:38:24<<
>>29 Jun 2020 10:38:24<<
>>29 Jun 2020 10:38:24<<
>>29 Jun 2020 10:38:24<<
>>29 Jun 2020 10:38:24<<
```

Perhaps `getline` caches. So I tried this

```
for f in {1..5}; do echo $f; sleep 2; done | awk '{ "date; : " NR | getline x; printf ">>NR=%d - %s<<\n", NR, x }'

>>NR=1 - 29 Jun 2020 10:44:05<<
>>NR=2 - 29 Jun 2020 10:44:07<<
>>NR=3 - 29 Jun 2020 10:44:09<<
>>NR=4 - 29 Jun 2020 10:44:11<<
>>NR=5 - 29 Jun 2020 10:44:13<<
```

All seems good. Caching (if that's what it is) is disabled and I get expected values from `date`.

I then continued down this path one more time, supplying repeated values in the command piped to `getline`

```
for f in 1 2 1 1 2 3; do echo $f; sleep 2; done | awk '{ "date; : " $1 | getline x; printf ">>NR=%d - f=%d - %s<<\n", NR, $1, x }'

>>NR=1 - f=1 - 29 Jun 2020 10:43:01<<
>>NR=2 - f=2 - 29 Jun 2020 10:43:03<<
>>NR=3 - f=1 - 29 Jun 2020 10:43:03<<
>>NR=4 - f=1 - 29 Jun 2020 10:43:03<<
>>NR=5 - f=2 - 29 Jun 2020 10:43:03<<
>>NR=6 - f=3 - 29 Jun 2020 10:43:11<<
```

I expected row 3 either to result in a new evaluation of the command (delivering a new date value) or else repeating the value from the first line. Neither happens.

This has stumped me. I don't understand is why I'm getting the same values for rows 2-5. Changing `f` from `1` to `2` clearly disabled any caching that was going on. But changing `f` from `2` back to `1` didn't give me the a cached copy of the first `f=1`, but repeated the value for `f=2`. Changing the command string to a new value with `f=3` triggered a new call to `date`.

Why?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110047/discussion-on-question-by-roaima-awk-date-getline-var-caches-its-value-but).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[GNU awk's manual mentions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html) that:

> If the same file name or the same shell command is used with `getline` more than once during the execution of an awk program (see section [Explicit Input with `getline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html)), the file is opened (or the command is executed) the first time only. At that time, the first record of input is read from that file or command. The next time the same file or command is used with `getline`, another record is read from it, and so on.

So it only runs the command once, and on further reads gets EOF, leaving the old value of `x` unchanged. Compare with what happens if we trash `x` after each read:

```
$ for f in {1..3}; do echo $f; sleep 2; done |
   awk '{ "date" | getline x; printf ">>%s<<\n", x; x ="done" }'
>>Mon Jun 29 13:37:53 EEST 2020<<
>>done<<
>>done<<
```

If we replace the `date` command here with something that keeps a record of when it runs, we can also see the record show it only get executed once.

`getline` also returns zero at EOF and -1 on error, so we could check that:

```
$ for f in {1..3}; do echo $f; sleep 2; done |
    awk '{ if (("date" | getline x) > 0) printf ">>%s<<\n", x;
           else printf "error or eof\n"; }'
>>Mon Jun 29 13:46:58 EEST 2020<<
error or eof
error or eof
```

You need to `close()` the pipe explicitly to have awk reopen it the next time.

```
$ for f in {1..3}; do echo $f; sleep 2; done |
   awk '{ "date" | getline x; printf ">>%s<<\n", x; x = "done"; close("date") }'
>>Mon Jun 29 13:39:19 EEST 2020<<
>>Mon Jun 29 13:39:21 EEST 2020<<
>>Mon Jun 29 13:39:23 EEST 2020<<
```

---

With `"date; : " NR | getline x;`, all the command lines are distinct, so you get a separate pipe for each.

With `"date; : " $1 | getline x;`, when `$1` repeats you get the same issue as in the first case, the second read to the same pipe hits EOF.

Comment: So if getline fails to get a line, it leaves the target variable unchanged? Ah! Light dawns! Thank you

Comment: @roaima, apparently so. I think you're supposed to check the return value :)

Comment: Also, awk holds all those distinct pipe handles open, so you will eventually run out of fd's and possibly other resources (like buffer space).

Comment: `("date" | getline x > 0)` is ambiguous, it needs to be `(("date" | getline x) > 0)` to be portable. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when/how to use getline.

Comment: Awesome answer. Just wanted to mention that if your command was `"date; : " NR | getline x; ` you can still close its pipe with `close("date; : " NR )`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear what "arbitrarily formatted" means, but GNU/awk time routines can do anything that date command can do, and more. If you care to show your actual inputs I can explain how to adapt this demo to a real application.

This script shows how to convert a text date from some arbitrary order (including month name) into datespec format, thence into seconds-since-epoch (which it then verifies using the external date command), then as ISO format, then adjusts it by arbitrary months, days and minutes.

The script:

```
#! /bin/bash

AWK='
BEGIN { 
    #.. Set up conversion from month names to numeric.
    split ("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec", V, / /);
    for (k in V) iMth[V[k]] = k;
    #.. These are only needed to verify the epoch using /bin/date.
    fmtSys = "echo -n \047/bin/date: \047; date -d \047 %s + %d secs\047 \047%s\047\n";
    Base = "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC";
    Date = "+%Y-%m-%d %T";
}
function Show (V, Local, ds, epoch) {
    printf ("\n");
    ds = sprintf ("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d", V[8], V[10], V[2], V[4], V[5], V[6], -1);
    epoch = mktime (ds);
    printf ("datespec: %s; epoch: %d\n", ds, epoch);
    printf ("ISO: %s\n", strftime ("%F %T %Z Week %W Day %w", epoch));
    #.. Call date command to verify.
    system (sprintf (fmtSys, Base, epoch, Date));
}
function Fix (tx, Local, ds, V) {
    split (tx, V, /[^A-Za-z0-9]/);
    V[10] = iMth[V[3]];
    Show( V);

    printf ("\n.. Go back 10 months and 43 days\n");
    V[10] -= 10; V[2] -= 43;
    Show( V);

    printf ("\n.. and forward 427 minutes\n");
    V[5] += 427;
    Show( V);
} 
{ printf ("\n.. Input date ::%s::\n", $0); }
{ Fix( $0); }
'

    printf 'Mon 29 Jun 16:04:42 BST 2020\n' | awk "${AWK}"
```

The test:

```
paul $ ./myDate

.. Input date ::Mon 29 Jun 16:04:42 BST 2020::

datespec: 2020 6 29 16 4 42 -1; epoch: 1593443082
ISO: 2020-06-29 16:04:42 BST Week 26 Day 1
/bin/date: 2020-06-29 16:04:42

.. Go back 10 months and 43 days

datespec: 2020 -4 -14 16 4 42 -1; epoch: 1563375882
ISO: 2019-07-17 16:04:42 BST Week 28 Day 3
/bin/date: 2019-07-17 16:04:42

.. and forward 427 minutes

datespec: 2020 -4 -14 16 431 42 -1; epoch: 1563401502
ISO: 2019-07-17 23:11:42 BST Week 28 Day 3
/bin/date: 2019-07-17 23:11:42
paul $
```

Comment: It's all very nice but it doesn't answer the question I asked (and it's not an XY problem). The missing part for me was awk's `close()`.

Comment: If you can now use `date` reliably from awk, that's good. I admit I never went right down the `info date` documentation before, and it does pick up an impressive number of variant formats. My concerns would be (1) can you reliably detect fails due to formats that it can't deal with; (2) What %age of your data would those failures impact; (3) Are the dates in your input clearly delineated -- if you send it spurious trailing characters, will it flag errors because of the extra text?

Answer (score -1):

We had the similar issue when processing a file containing log entries with date field in ISO8601 format
We were trying to find the difference between consecutive lines to find which step is taking time

**Below is the code initially Tried and got issue in Certain Places**

```
BEGIN {
FS="|"
}
{

#Not Working Script - Reason close() command was not done in date function
 "date -d " "\"" $1 "\"" " \"" "+%s%3N" "\""| getline curr_rec_ts;
 close(curr_rec_ts)
 elapsed=curr_rec_ts-prev_rec_ts
 print prev_rec_ts"|"curr_rec_ts"|"elapsed
 prev_rec_ts=curr_rec_ts
 prev_rec=$1"|"$7"|"$8"|"$12

}END {

}
```

Input File was contaiing records like below

```
# Input File
2024-03-08T18:34:09,669
2024-03-08T18:34:09,679
2024-03-08T18:34:09,679
2024-03-08T18:34:09,621
2024-03-08T18:34:09,621
2024-03-08T18:34:09,621
2024-03-08T18:34:09,667
2024-03-08T18:34:09,667
2024-03-08T18:34:09,668
2024-03-08T18:34:09,668
2024-03-08T18:34:09,669   // Many more
2024-03-08T18:34:09,669
2024-03-08T18:34:09,669
2024-03-08T18:34:09,669
2024-03-08T18:34:09,669  //Issue occured at this comparison
2024-03-08T18:34:09,861
2024-03-08T18:34:09,861
```

It was given difference as 193 ms ideally should be 192

Issue was due to fact getline cache for repeated date calls and give response similar one for subsequent operations

Solution was

```
#Apply Command and store in a variable 
cmd="date -d " "\"" $1 "\"" " \"" "+%s%3N" "\""
#
cmd| getline curr_rec_ts; 
# Key was this Below 
close(cmd)
```

Summary
Following things didn't work with close

**Case 1**

```
Getline::    "date -d " "\"" $1 "\"" " \"" "+%s%3N" "\""| getline curr_rec_ts;
Close ::     close("date") Didnt work as Original Command is different
```

**Case 2**

```
Getline ::  "date -d " "\"" $1 "\"" " \"" "+%s%3N" "\""| getline curr_rec_ts;
Close    ::   close(curr_rec_ts)   // Didnt work as it as no mean to close variable
```

**Case 3**

```
GetLine  :: cmd="date -d " "\"" $1 "\"" " \"" "+%s%3N" "\""
Close     :: close(cmd)  // work as full command was passed.
```

Comment: Because you don't close the commnad but you are wrongly closing the commnad result instead in `close(curr_rec_ts)`. so you were wrong and you didn't close the command correctly and so the solution you came with it is already [answered above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/595663/72456) and therefore your answer adds nothing.